# RichTextBox multi-line layout in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

If this has been asked before, sorry.

How can i set up different fonts in one RichTextBox using VB.NET? Because when i do this:

```
Dim String as String = "text" & vbCrLf & "more text"

Form.RichTextBox.Text = String
Form.RichTextBox.Select(String.IndexOf("Score: 5"), Len("Score: 5"))
Form.RichTextBox.SelectionFont = New Font(Presentatie.rtxtPresentatie.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold)
```

It will only make the "core: 5" part bold (tested this with selecting only, too, then it will only select the "core: 5" part).

Anyone help me? I need to get the answer very fast so please!

EDIT: Solved. Used this:

```
Form.RichTextBox.Select(String.IndexOf("Score: 5") - 1, Len("Score: 5"))
```

Thanks to codingbiz

Comment: side note; naming your variable `String` is not the best. Seems your index is one up - try `Form.RichTextBox.Select(myString.IndexOf("....") - 1)`

Comment: I know about the string, it's just for stackoverflow. I'll try this out in a minute.

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Bit strange, if i try this with other text it will work and throw an error when i use the - 1, maybe has to do with the space. Very weird.

Comment: @codingbiz: looks like you found a solution OP was looking for. Please post as an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't post my comment as answer because I was worried of when IndexOf returns 0, then -1 would throw an exception. So [here is the solution from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s.aspx)

```
 Public Sub SelectMyString()

    ' Create a string to search for the word "fox".
    Dim searchString As String = "fox"

    ' Determine the starting location of the word "fox".
    Dim index As Integer = Form.RichTextBox.IndexOf(searchString)

    ' Determine if the word has been found and select it if it was. 
    If index != -1 Then
       'Select the string using the index and the length of the string.
       Form.RichTextBox.Select(index, searchString.Length)
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, nice, but if someone has vb.net in his tag, please dont post C#. Just a side note. I understand it, tho.